# Thread assistance

Tags: android, multithreading

I need some help,

I am creating an app, and want it to run faster I mean when the app is started first it shows a blank white screen for o 1-2 seconds and then loads images. I have a layout background image, and 4 imageviews which are clickable and take you to the next activity. I read somewhere i should use threads to load images and it will load them on a separate thread faster, but i have some problem using it.

So here are the problems and android studio explanations:

```
Thread thread=new Thread( 

public void run(){ 

ImageView tipka=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tipkaproba); 

tipka.setImageResource(R.drawable.instructions); 

LinearLayout asd=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutproba); 

asd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backfround123); 

} 

).start();
```

Now the android studio says:

After

> "Thread(" )expected

Before

> "public void run(){"
>
> ; expected
>
> On ").start();"

Invalid method declaration; return type required, Missing method body, or declare abstract.

Now i would like to know:

1. Does this speed up loading images, ( if not how to do it then)
2. How to fix my errors.

Thanks anyway !

Comment: You may be interested in reading this : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html It will answer a lot of your questions !

Comment: Also check [Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728), a library that handles that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all images fit in the screen?! If users need to scroll to view other images why load all of them at once? Use a grid view with adapter to load the image. In this way when the app start only images on the screen will be loaded and then when the user scrolls other images show up!

another thing you can do is to have 2 version of each image. one low quality with small size that loads first and one for high quality image. that will load latter. You can also calculate the base color for each image (use open source code or do it manually). then set the background image of iamgeview to this color. So when the image finally loads on the screen. The difference is not as dramatic as it was before. 

If you want to use thread try AsyncTask first. Using AsyncTask is simpler than defining thread yourself. 

Try to decrease the size of your images! If you be able to do this. it works better than any other trick! It's mobile, you don't have to show supper high quality images. users don't even notice most of the time

You probably took care of this but it worth mentioning that you need to provide different images for different screen densities and it's critical for performance as well as quality.

Comment: Ok i really apritiate your answer, i have a a background that doesnt need to be too good with quality and i have imageviews as buttons because i wanted to make some sort of different letters so i made it in paint and had a large background to cover this mistake, now i found an easy way to make nice buttons so i will use them as imageview, i didnt use imagebutton because i wanted it to look like you pressed the text instead of a button. I wanted to find this out also because i thought to make an activity with my logo and after 5sec finishes and goes to mainactivity. But it isnt such a big deal!